# Difference between denote and represent

Tags: word-usage

> In Mathematics, a set is **denoted** by a capital letter and is **represented** by writing it in the roster form, set builder form and descriptive form.
>
> In Physics, a vector is **denoted** by a letter of the alphabet or the end points of the directed line segment which is representing it with an arrow(half or full) or a bar above or a tilde(~) below and is **represented** by a directed line segment drawn to scale whose length represents the magnitude of the vector and whose direction represents the direction of the vector.

The dictionary says:

> Denote - verb (used with object)
>
> 1.to be a mark or sign of; indicate:
>   A fever often denotes an infection.
>
> 2.to be a name or designation for; mean.
>
> 3.to represent by a symbol; stand as a symbol for.

---

> Represent - verb (used with object)
>
> 1.To serve to express, designate, stand for, or denote, as a word, symbol, or the like does; symbolize:
>   In this painting the cat represents evil and the bird, good.
>
> 2.To express or designate by some term, character, symbol, or the like:

The meaning of both the words seem similar to me

What is the difference between denotation and representation (denote and represent) and their usage? I guess that representation is some what related to description.

Comment: Hello, Mr.AP. It's a good practice to do some research of your own using commonly-available resources before asking a question here on ELU. Please consult a dictionary, and if you're still unsure, include your research in the post and then seek clarification. Thank you.

Comment: @TusharRaj done.

Comment: Good job. The post looks a lot better now. You might also want to provide a link to your quoted definitions, in case you got them online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not uncommon for technical subjects to assign specific senses to words which would be considered close synonyms in English. For example, a [thesaurus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/force) would tell you that `force`, `power`, and `energy` are all synonyms; while they all have distinct meanings in Physics.

In your case, `denote` is the word typically used in math/science to describe the symbol associated with something, (see sense 3); thus distinguishing it from `represent`, which is employed for diagrams and such.

In thinking that the words should be interchangeable, you might be considered guilty of [genetic fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_fallacy).

> The genetic fallacy (also known as the fallacy of origins or fallacy of virtue) is a fallacy of irrelevance where a **conclusion is suggested based solely on** someone's or **something's** history, **origin**, or source **rather than its current** meaning or **context**.

<sub>Wikipedia (emphasis mine)</sub>